# SP2010 - Scopes.GetDisplayGroup error, page visit required first?

Tags: 2010, powershell, search-scope

I'm having a very strange problem with the Scopes.GetDisplayGroup() method returning a "Specified cast is not valid" error.

This is a cut-down version of the code I've been using:

```
$SPWebApp = Get-SPWebApplication $spSiteUrl
$displayGroupName = "Search Dropdown"
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication "Search Service Application"
$scopes=New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.Scopes($ssa)

foreach ($SPSite in $SPWebApp.Sites) {
    $displayGroup = $scopes.GetDisplayGroup($SPSite.Url, $displayGroupName)
    ...
}
```

Through testing this on multiple environments and a lot of trial and error (as the issue was sporadic and didn't always occur consistently), I found that the way around it was to **visit the /_layouts/viewscopes.aspx page for each site collection in-browser first** before running the script. Once the page had been visited, the .GetDisplayGroup method works for that site collection without error and everything is hunky-dory.

This doesn't seem to make sense to me - does anyone have any idea why this could be happening? Is there any background code fired by that page when it's accessed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check if it is an issue of access rights for the account you are using to run the powershell script?

Answer (score 2):

I have come across this too, and yes, viewscopes.aspx causes the standard display groups to be created. I have written a post about my findings, and the work around I used: http://danielflint.im/2014/01/working-around-getdisplaygroup-throwing-invalid-cast-via-powershell/

Here's the work around:

```
Add-PSSnapIn Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue
[reflecton.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.Server") | Out-Null

# Get our site, search context and scopes
$site = Get-SPSite $siteUrl
$siteId = $site.Id.ToString("D")
$ctx = [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchContext]::GetContext($site)
$scopes = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.Scopes($ctx)

# Here's the cool stuff. We're really just calling $scopes.Consumers.EnsureRegistered($siteId)
$scopes.Consumers.EnsureRegistered($siteId)
$BindingFlags = [Reflection.BindingFlags] "NonPublic,Instance"

$consumers = $scopes.GetType().GetMember("Consumers",$BindingFlags)[0].GetValue($scopes, $null)
$consumer = $consumers.GetType().GetMethod("EnsureRegistered",$BindingFlags).Invoke($consumers, $siteId)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input Daniel - some interesting stuff there. Still a bit of a mystery as to why it behaves in this way to begin with, but good to know there's a workaround!